# TensorFlow on Windows 10 with Anaconda & Python 3.6

Tags: python, tensorflow, cygwin, windows-10, anaconda

Let me start by saying I am a beginner on Deep Learning and trying to find my way by following the Tensorflow tutorial, which is mainly applying the inception V3 method to the flowers data set.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining

which includes the following :

cd ~

curl -O (flower data link) -- **runs fine**

tar xzf flower_photos.tgz --**runs fine**

bazel build tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain **--error: no bazel command found**

In order to be able to follow this tutorial, I have also completed the Tensorflow installation tutorial and modified (replaced 35 to 36) it for Python 3.6 compatible whl as follows:  pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.2.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

Now back to the main question: After installing the flower data set and installing the bazel package, cygwin64. I went into the Bazel folder and ran the configure file as suggested in the forums as well as touch WORKSPACE and bagel build.  When I run the command "bazel build tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain" I still get the error: "Bazel command not found"

I followed similar questions on stackoverflow before openning up my own question, such as: questions- 41791171/bazel-build-for-tensorflow-inception-model and git clone'd the entire Tensorflow folder as instructed but resulted an eror of :bagel: command not found

To summarize, how can I run the Tensorflow Flowerset tutorial and overcome the errors of :bagel: command not found and :bazel: command not found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not mandatory to use **Bazel** for the [TensorFlow Image Retraining tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining).

You can also run the **retrain.py** located in the \tensorflow\examples\image_retraining\ folder cloned from the TensorFlow GitHub repo to retrain the Inception v3 model or Mobilenet model.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py

Put the Flowers datasets folder (**flower_photos**) under the image_retraining and run the retrain.py as below:

```
python retrain.py --image_dir flower_photos
```

You should see the script will download the Inception v3 model.
[image]

The image retraining in progress.
[image]

After the retraining is completed, you should see the below:
[image]

Copy both **output_graph.pb** and **output_labels.txt** in the C:\tmp folder, which are the retrain outputs to the image_retraining folder.
[image]

To verify the retrained model, you can run the **label_image.py** as below.
It should show the top 5 predictions.

```
python label_image.py --image=flower_photos\daisy\21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg --graph=output_graph.pb --labels=output_labels.txt
```

The expected output should be as below:

[image]

Comment: This is a great explanation! thank you, juvchan! I was able to run the inception V3 with the instructions you have provided. However, I am unable to locate the output_graph.pb and output_labels.txt nowhere :(

Comment: Hi @shaucha, those 2 files are generated only if you have run the retrain.py successfully. They should be output to your C:\tmp folder as shown in the updated answer above.

Comment: Kindly mark my answer as helpful and answer if you appreciate my effort and think.it has been helpful to you

Comment: yes - I just marked it as "solution" to my question and also upvoted it! :)

Comment: Thanks very much @shaucha :)